# Make a graph in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a project that I must use Three.js to render a 2D graph, does anyone know how to build a 2D graph in Three.js or any tutorial or good documentation?

Now I only have circles in the scene and they are not connected and spread with no criteria and a configured Camera with Orbit Controls.

```
function initialize() {

        // Create a scene
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x999999);

        // Create an orthographic camera


        const aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        if (aspectRatio < 1.0) {
            camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0 / aspectRatio, -1.0 / aspectRatio, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
        else {
            camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-aspectRatio, aspectRatio, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
        //camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio);
```

This is the WebGlRenderer and config to orbit controls and camera position

```
        // Create a renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        orbit.enableRotate = false;
        orbit.enablePan = true;
        orbit.mouseButtons = { LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN };
        orbit.touches = {
            ONE: THREE.TOUCH.DOLLY_PAN
        }

        camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        orbit.update();


        // Register the event handler to be called on window resize
        window.addEventListener('resize', windowResize);
```

Here is where I should position the nodes, the first parameter is a name(string) and the second is the position in the scene.

```
        //control = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        // Create five watches
        watch0 = new No(test.nomeCentra, new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 0.5, 0x999999, 0xffffff, 0x333333, 0xcccccc, 0xffffff, 0xff0000);
        scene.add(watch0.object);

        var posicaiXInicial = 0.5;
        var posicaiYInicial = 0.5;
        for (let i = 0; i < test.ligacoes.length; i++) {
            const directNodes = new No('New York', new THREE.Vector3(posicaiXInicial, posicaiYInicial, 0.0), 0.25, 0x999999, 0xffffff, 0x333333, 0xcccccc, 0xffffff, 0xff0000);
            posicaiXInicial += 0.5
            posicaiYInicial += 0.5
            posicaiXInicial *= -1
            scene.add(directNodes.object);
        }
```

I have positioned all the nodes and now I have to connect them with a line.